# Third-party js lib (jQuery + DataTable) not being loaded in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, third-party

I was trying to create a new LWC importing a third-party library that we already used in the past with VF but within a LWC.
We decided to use this one instead of lightning-datatable because we need a real-time filtering feature.

Following the LoadScript documentation, we imported both jQuery and DataTable libraries to Static Resources but when running the component we always get a "this.template.querySelector(...).DataTable is not a function"

Find hereby the html and js file of our component:

filteredTable.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="OST Events">
        <lightning-layout>
            <lightning-layout-item>
                    <table id="table_id" class="example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column 1</th>
                                <th>Column 2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                                <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                <template if:true={error}>
                    <c-error-panel errors={error}></c-error-panel>
                </template>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

filteredTable.js:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import DATATABLE from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/dataTablesv10_18';
import JQUERY from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jQuery';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class FilteredTable extends LightningElement {
    DataTable;
    @track error;
    @track dataExample;
    @track successMessage = '';

    dataTablejsInitialized = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.dataTablejsInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.dataTablejsInitialized = true;
        loadScript(this,JQUERY)
        .then(()=>{
            Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, DATATABLE+'/DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'),
            loadStyle(this, DATATABLE+'/DataTables-1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')
            ])
            .then(()=>{
                this.showSuccessMessage();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error loading DataTables',
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading DataTables',
                    message: error.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });  
    }

    showSuccessMessage() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        this.template.querySelector('.example').DataTable();
    }

}
```

I followed the library documentation hereby:
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html

Thanks!
edit: Deleted a test line with the standard jQuery selector that I tested and corrected the selector to only match .example class.

Comment: Isint your classname example? Why are you using table.example?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the Promise.All approach before.

I switched to just calling loadScript and loadStyle outside of Promise.All

If you do this:

```
loadStyle(this,DATATABLE+'/DataTables-1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css');
loadScript(this,DATATABLE+'/DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js');
```

And not inside of a Promise.All I believe it will load and work.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I tried to make the loadScript and loadStyle outside of the Promise.All and create them in order (first the jQuery and then the DataTable) but i got the same result.

Comment: For your static resource did you set the proper content type? Can you share the structure of the static zip file?